# Simulating systems of SDEs in Mathematica and plotting solutions.

Tags: mathematica, stochastic-differential-equations

I would like to simulate the solution of the following system of SDE's:
\begin{equation*}\begin{split} 
                 dX(t) &= - \frac{1}{2}X(t)\, dt - Y(t)\, dW(t)\\
                 dY(t)  &= -\frac{1}{2}Y(t)\, dt + X(t)\, dW(t).
\end{split}\end{equation*}
I am using Mathematica for this purpose and in particular the built-in function **ItoProcess**. I can model each equation separately.  But what is the syntax to write both equations so that they use the same brownian motion $W(t) $ ? I checked the documentation in Mathematica, but I cannot quite make out the form to use. 
Also, once the simulation is done, the result is reported as TemporalData. I would like a plot of (X(t), Y(t)) and not separate plots of $(X(t), t) $ and $(Y(t), t). $  Is there a way to do that?

Sorry if the question is not too challenging, but I tried to use what I know for bi- or tri-dimensional Wiener processes in Mathematica and no success as I assume that ItoProcess works somewhat differently.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Maurice

Comment: I don't know how Mathematica works here, but I assume you can take two BMs and use a diffusion matrix that just ignores one of them. It might be inefficient but That is probably OK.

Answer (score 0):

After some trials and errors.. I think I solved my own question.
The program allows also to use two different Brownian motions. In my case I wanted the same to be used to produce the motion on a circle. I also added a graphic of the result I got. The parameters should be easy to modify.

Maurice

[image: Mathematica code to produce bivariate Ito processes.]

[image]